# Getting the address of a pointer and convert it in a wxString

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxstring

I'm trying to convert the address of a pointer to a wxString of the wxWidgets library.

I have this book that presents a console based example to explain the input/output stream system in C++. Here we can print the address of some pointers without much complications using

```
const char *const variable = "again";
cout << static_cast<void*>(variable);
```

So far I can understand the example but (Now the complication)I want to make some GUI off the examples to train myself and explore the wxWidgets classes along with the book. I've successfully made some conversions with the As() method of the wxAny class and even compiled it without warnings or errors. But in execution time I get an "Assert failure" when trying to convert the types.

If I let the program continue it prints in my wxTextCtrl things like:

> ﻌњ̎X(

Any ideas??
(btw I use CodeBlocks with Mingw32 and wxWidgets 3.0 in a windows 7 system)
this is the code that gives me the assert failure:

```
void ConsoleFrame::OnbtnFrase2Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
string chaine2("Value of the pointer: ");
void* puntero = &chaine2;
wxAny anyThing= puntero;
consoleText->AppendText(anyThing.As<wxString>());
}
```

This is the method that gives me the assert failure error.
Thanks to @Grady for correcting the code before.
Seems that I cannot convert a void* to a wxString. I have a gist of what may the problem be but, I cannot find a solution to the original problem of printing the address of a pointer in a text control (NOT the console screen)

Comment: Can you put a code snippet that gives you the "Assert Failure". It would be easier for the audience to understand this way what the problem really is.

Comment: Do you want to print the *address* of the variable or the contents of the C-Style string?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want the wxTextCtrl to contain a human-readable representation of the address of the memory location where `variable` is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to do what you want in C++ is using [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) (you need to `#include <sstream>`). The body of your function would then look like this:

```
string chaine2("Value of the pointer: ");
void* puntero = &chaine2;
stringstream tmpss;
tmpss << chaine2 << puntero;
consoleText->AppendText(tmpss.str());
```

If you just want to get a `wxString` containing everything that was output to that stream, you just do something like:

```
wxString mystr = tmpss.str();
```

Comment: Thank you bogdan! This will greatly help me. The thing I was afraid of was to lean too much on methods "outside" the standard library. It's good to know how things are done commonly, sometimes we get things to work with complicated turnarounds when there are already simpler solutions available.

Comment: @RainMaker Cheers! Using the standard library whenever possible is the way to go. For this example, keep in mind that there's also `std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream`. Just like for the other types of streams, it's generally a good idea to use the corresponding kind of stream for the operations you need (input or output). Here I used the one that supports both out of sheer laziness.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your question has to do with wxWidgets, but this works for me:

```
const char * dog = "dog";
std::cout << &dog;
```

I am no C++ expert.. but to me that looks like "output address of variable dog"

and if you want that as a string you could use a C++ string stream or just happy old C `sprintf`

```
char * addrString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(void *) * 2 + 3); //  *2 bytes for hex rep, +3 for "0x" and null
sprintf(addrString, "%p",dog);
```

Comment: Helle Grady, that would work in a console-based program but here I use wxSmith in CodeBlocks (like I said before) to make a GUI to try to output the address of the pointer in a text control. So far I can print some unreadable characters using the wxAny class and the method .As().

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the address of a pointer and the contents of the pointer, especially with C-style (nul terminated sequence of characters).

For example:

```
const char * const text = "Some Text\n";
```

The variable `text` is a *pointer* to a string literal.  The contents of the pointer is the location where the string literal resides; often called an *address*.

The expression, `&text`, represents the location or the address of the *pointer*.  So if the pointer is residing at address 0x4000, the expression `&text` would return 0x4000; not the content of the pointer.

There are examples on StackOverflow for printing the *address* of a variable and the contents or the C-Style string.

So, do you want a `wxString` containing the address of a pointer or the string literal that the pointer points to?

Comment: Hello Thomas, I want a wxString that contain the address of the pointer. Not the value pointed by the pointer. Seems that myquestion is too complicated I will update it adding the code that gets me the errors.

Answer (score 0):

At last!!

The answer to my question was here:

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html

This is the documentation of the text control. I just had to REDIRECT the output stream to the text control with:

```
wxStreamToTextRedirector redirect(myTextControl);
```

And now I use the cout object normally,

```
cout<<puntero;
```

and the output will be presented in the text control instead of a console screen. I could not create the wxString containing the address but so far this can at least show it. I know that from here on I can create a string from the contents of the text control and the member functions of it. If any of you guys have a better answer, I will gladly accep it. It is funny how the chapter of the book where I am is in/out streams and the solution to my problem is not presented in the book.